# How to get the values from the following array?

Tags: php, arrays

I got the following array as a result of an output from a web service? I printed the values in the array using the `print_r()` method as stated in the following description.

**ARRAY OUTPUT:**

```html
Array
 ( [0] => stdClass Object 
 ( [return] => stdClass Object
 ( [data] => stdClass Object 
 ( 
 [status] => 50000 
 [adminUser] => 1 
 [atdUserid] => 58 
 [category] => [client] => [cur_designation] => TL 
 [currentEmpId] => E058
 [digitPrefix] => 8,5,1,3,7,0
 [email] => jaliya@codegen.net 
 [employeeId] => 58 
 [employee_status] => 1 
 [firstName] => Jaliya 
 [lastName] => Seneviratna 
 [last_login_date] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 6 [month] => 2 [year] => 2015 )
 [letterPrefix] => D,C,U,T,Z,E 
 [loginName] => jaliya 
 [resourceStatus] => 
 [taskPassword] => d6188c72995d80e1a8e00d34987e0f6b 
 [userId] => 118 ) 
 [reason] => Success 
 [refetch] => 1 
 [status] => 1 
    ) ) )
```

I got the above array by calling a webservice in php. I want to get the details out of this array. And the problem was that I couldn't get the `stdClass` objects casted into the right type. I tried the following code but it is not working. Can anyone help me to get the values inside the `data[]` out in php. I used the following code and it is not working and giving an exception.

**CODE USED:**

```
 print_r(array_values($quote));
 echo $quote[0]->data;
```

The exception was the following...

**EXCEPTION RECIEVED:**

```
 Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$data in                                      C:\xampp\htdocs\WebServiceDemo-php\democlient.php on line 27
```

How to get values out from this array?
Please help me...

Comment: Dude, may be possible its a json response, so parse it...

Comment: did you try echo $quote[0]->return->data;

Comment: Hey I don't know how to pass... can you tell me how..

Answer (score 0):

convert the object in to array using this function

```
get_object_vars(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

USE Can Print each key value of data array like this:-

```
 echo $quote[0]->data->status;
```

I will Print

```
50000
```